# Shouldn't the increasing of the stored memory address of a pointer depend on the system's architecture?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, architecture

Consider the following `C` code

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int arr[] = {10, 20, 30, 40};
    int *ptr = arr; // ptr points to the internal pointer variable of `arr`, that is, the address of its first array element, 10.

    printf("The address of the first int array element is                 : %p\n"
           "The stored value (.i.e., the memory address) of the pointer is: %p\n",
           (void*)&arr[0], (void*)ptr);

    printf("The memory size the a int variable is: %zu bytes, which is equal to %lu bits (each byte has 8 bits).\n"
           "Since `ptr` is a int pointer, the command `ptr = ptr + 1` shifts stored memory address of `ptr` in %zu bytes.\n\n",
            sizeof(int), 8*sizeof(int), sizeof(int));

    ptr = ptr + 1; // Move ptr to the memory address of the next integer (20) (instead, you could use `ptr++`)
    printf("The address of the first int array element is                 : %p\n"
           "The stored value (.i.e., the memory address) of the pointer is: %p\n\n",
           (void*)&arr[0], (void*)ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

It prints:

```
The address of the first int array element is                : 0x7ffe100ee500
The store value (.i.e., the memory address) of the pointer is: 0x7ffe100ee500

The memory size the a int variable is: 4 bytes, which is equal to 32 bits (each byte has 8 bits).
Since `ptr` is a int pointer, the command `ptr = ptr + 1` shifts stored memory address of `ptr` in 4 bytes.

The address of the first int array element is                : 0x7ffe100ee500
The store value (.i.e., the memory address) of the pointer is: 0x7ffe100ee504
```

However it contradicts the way I am reasoning over memory address and the system memory's architecture:

- I am on a 64-bit system, which means that each memory address stores 64 bits, or equivalently, 8 bytes.
- The memory address of my first integer element array is `0x7ffe100ee500`
- Since each memory address stores up to 8 bytes and my `C` `int` variable is 4-bytes-sized, one memory address is enough to store it (I suppose the remaining 4 bytes in `0x7ffe100ee500` is simply ignored).
- The code `ptr = ptr + 1` makes the the pointer's stored value (i.e., the memory address `0x7ffe100ee500`) move forward 4 bytes.
- Since each memory address stores up to 8 bytes, shifting the memory address to `0x7ffe100ee501` would be enough.

However, I am getting `0x7ffe100ee504`, as if each memory address contained 1 byte only. Can someone please give me a help to understand it?

Comment: To be fair, *there are* machines where each address represent a word and each word is more than 1 byte. But these machines are rare and I am not sure if they were used during previous decades. On most modern architectures memory is organized in bytes.

Comment: @Gerhardh There are various DSP using 16 bit bytes still in use. But anyone writing C for those and expecting it to be just like any other program has serious problems not related to programming. And out of tradition, DSPs are almost always programmed in assembler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am on a 64-bit system, which means that each memory address stores 64 bits, or equivalently, 8 bytes.

False.  Each addressable memory address, *by definition*, stores 1 byte.  Having a 64 bit system means that an address is a 64 bit value.

So given your example of a 32 bit `int` whose starting address is 0x7ffe100ee500, that value occupies the addresses 0x7ffe100ee500, 0x7ffe100ee501, 0x7ffe100ee502, and 0x7ffe100ee503.

Comment: And, by definition, 1 *byte* is `CHAR_BIT` (usually `8`) bits long.

Comment: "Having a 64 bit system means that an address is a 64 bit value." Bit of an over-simplification. "64 bit system" refers to the word size of a data register that the CPU can handle in a single instruction. Whereas the size of the addresses depends on the width of the _address bus_. By convention, mainstream 64 bit CPUs also have 64 bit buses. But if you look at for example common 8 bit CPUs on the market, this is not the case. Almost every 8-bit CPU has a 16 bit address bus.

Comment: N.B. The *definition* that this is *by*, is the C standard's. On a machine where every addressable memory location stores 64 bits, `CHAR_BIT` would have to be 64, and `sizeof(char)` would have to still be 1. (And probably `sizeof(int)` would also be 1. And the operating system could not claim POSIX compliance.)